# Need a blank cell when IF cell is blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

*Long time listener, first time caller...*

I'm sure this is simple, but I don't know how to do it.
I am putting together a very simple spreadsheet that will autopopulate the correct shift when a manager is input into a cell.  I need to do this cell by cell, because some of the managers overlap shifts.

In place of "name" and "shift" I have the actual manager and shift, but for simplicity sake I have:

=IF(K21="NAME", "SHIFT1", "SHIFT2")

and that works just fine for this because there are only 2 managers with different shifts.

However, when there are no manager names in K21, it still gives me a shift in the other cell.

How do I leave that blank until the manager name is filled in?

(I will also need to have several other "IF" statements in other cells, as there are more managers on those shifts, and nested IF statements are telling me there are too many arguments.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using your `IF` as the second argument for another `IF` that would check if the Manager cell is empty:

`=IF(ISBLANK(K21),"",IF(K21="NAME","SHIFT1","SHIFT2"))`

Answer (score 0):

However I would just go with vlookup() like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K21,$Q$20:$R$21,2,0),"Not in list")
```

and then you can have a list of names and shifts and even add a 3rd column with weekend shifts...

So trap the blank first:

```
=if(k21="","",your if here)
```

But if k21 has other text then you may need to consider something else, perhaps a list of valid names:

```
=if(iferror(vlookup(k21,list,1,0),0)>=1,your if here,"")
```

That list can be a range of cells or just both the names.

See:
[image]

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K21,Q20:Q21,1,0),0)>=1,IF(K21="Fred","SHIFT1",IF(K21="Julie","SHIFT2","Error1")),"Not in List")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you'll have multiple `if` statements, you might consider doing a table and then a lookup. Here's a [simple example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PdRYpDYJBfPh1_RMySymjD-s1jhPGc7V03r3VcHK4yY/edit?usp=sharing) based on the idea of you have your managers and shifts in column `a` and `b` and you type the managers name in cell `D2` (or `K21` in your case). This would also account for a for blank entry compared to a WRONG entry......

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,FALSE),"Not listed!"))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]